# Create a form with the appearance of a menu

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, button, user-interface

How can I create a menu like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that customize a `Form`.

http://www.vcskicks.com/custom_shape_form_region.php

The steps to follow are the following:

- Scan the `Bitmap` for the contrast color
- Add the color's location as a `Rectangle` to a `GraphicsPath` object
- Create a custom shaped `Region` from the `GraphicsPath` object